# Why is Angular Slick Grid not rendering CSS?

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I have a new Angular 12 project that I am trying to have an angular slick grid grid in. But all the data is piled on top of itself, as shown in the photo.
[image: What is happening]

I'm using code from [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-add-slickgrid-a-best-performing-excel-sheet-like-datagrid-liberary-in-angular-7-web-app/) and it's obviously creating the table, but not styling it. I also have fixed all the errors in the console by adding the ngx-translate/core stuff but that didn't do anything. I've been working on this since 10am and haven't gotten anywhere.

here is my angular.json:
[image: Angular.json]

here is the html, again, taken from the link above.

```
<div class="container">
    <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
                 [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [dataset]="dataset">
   </angular-slickgrid>
</div>
```

And here is the ts. Again, taken straight from the website link that I posted

```
this.columnDefinitions = [
  { id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title', sortable: true },
  { id: 'duration', name: 'Duration (days)', field: 'duration', sortable: true },
  { id: '%', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete', sortable: true },
  { id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start' },
  { id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish' },
  { id: 'effort-driven', name: 'Effort Driven', field: 'effortDriven', sortable: true }
];
this.gridOptions = {
  enableAutoResize: true,       // true by default
  enableCellNavigation: true
};

// fill the dataset with your data
// VERY IMPORTANT, Angular-Slickgrid uses Slickgrid DataView which REQUIRES a unique "id" and it has to be lowercase "id" and be part of the dataset
this.dataset = [];

// for demo purpose, let's mock a 1000 lines of data
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const randomYear = 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  const randomMonth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  const randomDay = Math.floor((Math.random() * 28));
  const randomPercent = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  this.dataset[i] = {
    id: i, // again VERY IMPORTANT to fill the "id" with unique values
    title: 'Task ' + i,
    duration: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '',
    percentComplete: randomPercent,
    start: `${randomMonth}/${randomDay}/${randomYear}`,
    finish: `${randomMonth}/${randomDay}/${randomYear}`,
    effortDriven: (i % 5 === 0)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you're missing the proper CSS styling for Angular-Slickgrid, you should follow the [HOWTO - Step by Step](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step) Wiki to get started and in your case the [Step 3](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step#3-css--sass-styles), where you have to choose between CSS or SASS imports.

The best way to get started is to:

1. read the [HOWTO - Step by Step](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step)
2. and/or git clone the [Angular-Slickgrid-Demos](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos)

I created a lot of Wikis and Examples, so consulting them first is always good to do.

Please note that I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid)

So in summary if you're using CSS, then you need to do this change in your `angular.json` file

```js
"styles": [
    // ...
    "node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/styles/css/slickgrid-theme-bootstrap.css"
],
```

Comment: I temporarily moved on to a different project because I was angry with SlickGrid, but i will give it a try here next week and come back and upvote this if it works. Thank you so much for commenting!!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your angular.json contains a theme for slickgrid, otherwise the grid shows exactly like yours:

"node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/styles/css/slickgrid-theme-bootstrap.css"

Answer (score 0):

I use React and ran into the same problem, in my case it helped me to add the line

```
import '../node_modules/@slickgrid-universal/common/dist/styles/css/slickgrid-theme-bootstrap.css';
```

To the index.jsx file.